# Get "value" from characteristic

Tags: swift3, core-bluetooth

The following...

```
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        print(characteristic)
    }
```

..outputs...

```
<CBCharacteristic: 0x1700b8180, UUID = FFE1, properties = 0x10, value = <01>, notifying = YES>
```

I want the "value" part "01".

Comment: `characteristic.value` will give a NSData object `<01>`, but it's up to you to transform that hex into the value you want (string encoding? int value?, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth/cbcharacteristic) you can access it by calling:
`characteristic.value`, this will be an object of type `Data`.
Then you can transform this object to string.
Like this:

```
let data = characteristic.value
var dataString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

Comment: That outputs Optional("\u{01}"). How can I get just the 01?

Comment: I'm wanting to do a condition: if dataString == "01 { //do stuff }

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank OOPer on the Apple Developer Forums for this answer.

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {  
    guard let data = characteristic.value else {  
        return  
    }  
    if data.elementsEqual([0x01]) { //<- You can directly compare a Data to an Array of bytes.  
        //do something  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking to parse the data when Peripheral communicates.

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor   characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
        print("ERROR didUpdateValue \(error)")            
        return
    }
 //BLE_Characteristic_uuid > Your BLE Char UUID
    if characteristic.uuid == CBUUID(string: BLE_Characteristic_uuid) {
        guard let value = characteristic.value else { return }
        
        let content = String(data: value, encoding:.utf8)?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) ?? ""//.filter { !" \n\t\r".contains($0) } ?? ""
        print("Value Received:-->",content )
        if let i = content.utf8.firstIndex(where: { $0 >= 32 })     {
           if let asciiPrefix = String(content.utf8[..<i]) {
             print(asciiPrefix)
            }
        }else{
            return
        }
    }
}
```

The ASCII value of **32** corresponds to the space character (' '). Therefore, the expression content.utf8.firstIndex(where: { $0 >= 32 }) returns the index of the first non-control character in the UTF-8 representation of the content String. However you can control it as per your requirements.

> 32 (in ASCII, these are printable characters like letters, digits, punctuation, etc.).

> String(content.utf8[..<i]): This creates a new String using a substring of the content string from its start (0) up to the index i (excluding i). In other words, it extracts the portion of the string up to the first non-control ASCII character (whose ASCII value is greater than or equal to 32) and assigns it to asciiPrefix.

It will also neglect  \u{01}

Answer (score -1):

swift:
Get value from characteristic while update value.

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

        let value = characteristic.value

        print(value)
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.